# How can I upload multiple images using Active storage and jbuilder instead of 1 image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activestorage

This is what I currently have in my Vision model:

```
    has_one_attached :image
    belongs_to :user

    def featured_image_url
        if self.image.attachment
          self.image.attachment.service_url
        end
      end
end
```

in my Vision controller:

```
    def create
        @vision = current_user&.visions.create(vision_params)
        render :create, status: :created
    end


    def vision_params
        params.permit(:description, :image)
    end
```

and in _vision.json.jbuilder:

```
json.call(
    vision,
    :id,
    :description,
    :created_at,
    :updated_at
)

json.image_url  polymorphic_url(vision.image)
```

I am using Amazon S3 for image storage. How can I change my code to be able to upload multiple image files?

Please also bear in mind that I have existing data in my database where I am getting an image URL for one single Image per Vision. How can I make the changes without affecting my existing database?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

You need specify `has_many_attached` in your model and your controller need be prepare to receive a array of images. Something like this:

```
def vision_params
  params.permit(:description, images: [])
end
```

See the doc: https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#has-many-attached

Comment: @OzgeCokyasar add the erro detail on your question. This approach like the doc would be the right way.